# Python join method inserting string rather than concatenating

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a method that takes in a file and then convert its file name into a string of random characters without changing the extension. However, somehow the `.join()` method is acting a bit unexpectedly by inserting the new string into the original string.

Minimal reproducible example:

```
import string
import random

random_string = "".join(random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for _ in range(10))
extension = "IMG_4078.JPG".rsplit(".", 1)[1]
filename = random_string.join([".", extension])
print(f"Random string: {random_string}")
print(f"Extension: {extension}")
print(f"File name: {filename}")
```

Result:

```
Random string: BgjnFKrLvc
Extension: JPG
File name: .BgjnFKrLvcJPG
```

I was expecting it to be `BgjnFKrLvc.JPG` and I wonder where am I doing it wrong.

Edit: Out of curiosity, I ran the `timeit` module to compare the two solutions `filename = f"{random_string}.{extension}"` versus `filename = ".".join([random_string, extension])`. The former one ended up being slightly faster after I ran each 1M times (62.87387199999648s versus 63.04620390000491s respectively).

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: `filename = '.'.join([random_string, extension])` or `filename = f"{random_string}.{extension}"`

Comment: That is not how `join()` works. Every beginner I have ever taught has a problem with this. It goes `delimiter.join(list_of_pieces)`. There is a good reason for this but it is not immediately apparent (unless you're Dutch).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are generating the random string right, you are getting the extension right, now simply concat them as:

```
filename = f"{random_string}.{extension}"
```

Alternative to f-string:

```
filename = "{}.{}".format(random_string, extension)
```

Answer (score 1):

`join()` method returns a string by joining all the elements of an iterable separated by a string separator. In `random_string.join(extension)`, your string separator is `random_string`. That's why you get something weird like

```
import string
import random

random_string = "".join(random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for _ in range(10))
extension = "IMG_4078.JPG".rsplit(".", 1)[1]
filename = random_string.join(extension)

print(f"Random string: {random_string}")
print(f"Extension: {extension}")
print(f"File name: {filename}")
# Random string: Q1ZZbHEIdC
# Extension: JPG
# File name: JQ1ZZbHEIdCPQ1ZZbHEIdCG
```

For the correct implementation, use

```py
filename = '.'.join([random_string, extension])
```

Answer (score 1):

The grammar of the join method is counter-intuitive. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

> str.join(iterable)¶ Return a string which is the concatenation of the
> strings in iterable. A TypeError will be raised if there are any
> non-string values in iterable, including bytes objects. The separator
> between elements is the string providing this method.

It's useful if you need the same separator several times or if you already have the things you want to concatenate in a list like when creating your `random_string`.

For just concatenating arbitrary strings there are two clearer ways to write it:

- Use the concatenation operator (`+`): `filename = random_string + "." + extension`
- Or use an f-string: `filename = f"{random_string}.{extension}"`